# Stream Subscription Cancel or Pause flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

The code below works fine, listening changes from firestore, but for some reason it does not stop of listening values, even after streamSub.cancel().
Someone knows the reason?

This is a pagination for chat app, which it receive changes from two collections from firestore in pagination system.

Thats the part of the code:

```
StreamSubscription<List<QuerySnapshot>>? streamSub;
  ValueNotifier<List<MessageTileModel>> _allPagedResults = ValueNotifier([]);
  static const int loadLimit = 5;
  DocumentSnapshot? _lastDocument;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Future<Null> _getData() async {
    try {
      Query pagechatQuery = firestore
          .collection("messages")
          .where('users', arrayContains: localUserData.value.id!)
          .orderBy('lastMsg', descending: true)
          .limit(loadLimit);
      if (_lastDocument != null) {
        pagechatQuery = pagechatQuery.startAfterDocument(_lastDocument!);
      }
      final msgStream = pagechatQuery
          .withConverter<MessageTileModel>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
                MessageTileModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
          )
          .snapshots();

      final userStream = msgStream.flatMap(
        (msg) {
          List<dynamic> filterUsers = msg.docs
              .map((e) => e.data().isGroup == false
                  ? e.data().idTo != localUserData.value.id
                      ? e.data().idTo
                      : e.data().idFrom
                  : null)
              .whereNotNull()
              .toList();

          return filterUsers.isEmpty
              ? firestore
                  .collection('empty')
                  .withConverter<UserModel>(
                    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
                        UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
                    toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
                  )
                  .snapshots()
              : firestore
                  .collection("users")
                  .where('id', whereIn: [
                    ...{...filterUsers}
                  ])
                  .withConverter<UserModel>(
                    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
                        UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
                    toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
                  )
                  .snapshots();
        },
      );

      streamSub = CombineLatestStream.list([msgStream, userStream])
          .listen((List<QuerySnapshot> value) async {
        QuerySnapshot<MessageTileModel> msgS =
            value.elementAt(0) as QuerySnapshot<MessageTileModel>;
        QuerySnapshot<UserModel> userS =
            value.elementAt(1) as QuerySnapshot<UserModel>;
        if (msgS.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          msgS.docChanges.forEach((change) {
            MessageTileModel msg = change.doc.data()!;

            peerId =
                msg.idTo != localUserData.value.id! ? msg.idTo : msg.idFrom;

            int i = userS.docs.indexWhere((e) => e.id == peerId);
            if (i >= 0) {
              msg = msg.copyWith(userData: userS.docs[i].data());
            }

            switch (change.type) {
              case DocumentChangeType.added:
                _allPagedResults.value.add(msg);
                break;

              case DocumentChangeType.removed:
                _allPagedResults.value.removeWhere((e) => e.id == msg.id);
                break;
              default:
            }
            if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified ||
                userS.docChanges
                        .map((e) => e.type == DocumentChangeType.modified)
                        .toList()
                        .length !=
                    0) {
              print("changed here");
              int index = _allPagedResults.value
                  .indexWhere((element) => element.id == msg.id);
              if (index >= 0) {
                _allPagedResults.value[index] = msg;
              }
            }
          });
          _hasMoreData.value = msgS.docs.length == loadLimit;
          _lastDocument = msgS.docs.last;
          _allPagedResults.value = await List.from(_allPagedResults.value)
            ..sort((a, b) {
              if (a.lastMsg == null && b.lastMsg == null) {
                return 0;
              } else if (a.lastMsg == null) {
                return -1;
              } else if (b.lastMsg == null) {
                return 1;
              } else {
                return b.lastMsg!.compareTo(a.lastMsg!);
              }
            })
            ..unique((e) => e.id);
        } else {
          _hasMoreData.value = false;
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSub?.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }
```